# jquery delay slideup

Tags: jquery, delay, slideup

does any one know why this not working

```
$(window).load(function() {

      $('#first-div').animate({top:"640px"},3000);
      $('#second-div').delay(5000).slideup("1000");
      });
```

what I'm trying to do is when load the page, the first div to move down using animation and second div use slide up after delay.

My problem is that the first div is works fine, but the second div is not working, is not doing anything using .delay()

does anyone can help me please.

AM

Answer (score 0):

The `u` in `slideUp` must be capital. http://jsfiddle.net/L4AaR/

```
$('#second-div').delay(5000).slideUp("1000");
```

Comment: thanks but still not working either slideup or slideUP. Any other idea!

Comment: @user1953826 it works fine in the fiddle. I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setTimeout()`:

```
$(window).load(function() {

  $('#first-div').animate({top:"640px"},3000);
  setTimeout(function(){
      $('#second-div').slideUp("1000");
  }, 5000);
});
```

Hope it helps